# Implementing context switch - 2nd function does not run again

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm trying to implement context switching using C++ and inline assembly(AT&T) on x86-64.
It seems to be working correctly if I save and reload context for the same function.
However, when I try to yield the functions, it gave me seg fault/corrupt stack using GDB after trying to load the 2nd function context.

For example, it prints
Print1
Print2
Print1
// Corrupt stack and program stops running

However, if I were to save context of thread 1(1st function) before reloading it, there would be no problems.

For example, it prints
Print1
Print1
Print1

I'm creating memory space for context saving and stack. When saving context, stack pointer and base pointer would be saved into a struct. After that, stack pointer will point to the context memory to push register values.

I would like to know what causes the corrupt stack and why I can't load 2nd function's context back. And if possible, please kindly help me to point out any errors in my code. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
namespace CORO
{
using ThreadID = unsigned;
static int thread_count;

enum STATE
{
  READY,
  ACTIVE,
  WAITING,
  ENDED
};

struct thd_data
{
  int parent_ID = 0;
  int id = 0;
  STATE state = READY;

  int * stack_mem;
  void * stackptr;
  void * stackbp;
  void*(*funcptr)(void*);
  void * param = nullptr;
  int * context_mem;
  int * context_sp;

  thd_data()
  :stack_mem{new int[1024]}, context_mem{new int[1024]} 
  {

  }

  thd_data(const thd_data & rhs)
  :stack_mem{new int[1024]}, context_mem{new int[1024]} 
  {

  }

  thd_data & operator=(const thd_data & rhs)
  {

  }
};

static thd_data* curr_thd;

std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<thd_data>> threadmap;
std::vector<int>activeListID;

// Returns a pointer to next thread
thd_data * FindNextThread()
{
  int new_id;
  for(const auto & elem : activeListID)
  {
    if(elem != curr_thd->id)
    {
      new_id = elem;
      break;
    }
  }
  auto threadmap_elem = threadmap.find(new_id);
  if(threadmap_elem != threadmap.end())
  {
    return &(*threadmap_elem->second);
  }
  else
  {
    return nullptr;
  }
}

void thd_init()
{
  threadmap[0] = std::make_shared<thd_data>();
  auto main_thd = threadmap.find(0)->second;

  main_thd->state = ACTIVE;
  main_thd->id = 0;
  main_thd->param = nullptr;
  main_thd->funcptr = nullptr;
  activeListID.push_back(main_thd->id);

  curr_thd = &(*main_thd);
}

ThreadID new_thd( void*(*func)(void*), void *param)
{
  thread_count += 1; // increment counter

  threadmap[thread_count] = std::make_shared<thd_data>();
  auto thd = threadmap.find(thread_count)->second;

  thd->state = READY;
  thd->id = thread_count;
  activeListID.push_back(thd->id);

  thd->stackptr = thd->stack_mem+1024;
  thd->stackbp = thd->stack_mem;
  thd->funcptr = func;
  thd->param = param;
  return thd->id;
}

void thd_yield()
{
  // Find the next ready thread
  thd_data* thd = FindNextThread();

  if(thd == nullptr)
    return;

  // Move ID to the end of vector
  activeListID.erase(std::remove(activeListID.begin(), activeListID.end(), curr_thd->id), activeListID.end());
  activeListID.push_back(curr_thd->id);

  // Save context
  {
    asm volatile
    (
      "movq %%rsp, %0\n\t" // save stack pointer
      "movq %%rbp, %1\n\t" // save rbp
      "movq %3, %%rsp\n\t" // point to context mem then push register values into it
      "pushq %%rax\n\t"
      "pushq %%rbx\n\t"
      "pushq %%rcx\n\t"
      "pushq %%rdx\n\t"
      "pushq %%rsi\n\t"
      "pushq %%rdi\n\t"
      "pushq %%r8\n\t"
      "pushq %%r9\n\t"
      "pushq %%r10\n\t"
      "pushq %%r11\n\t"
      "pushq %%r12\n\t"
      "pushq %%r13\n\t"
      "pushq %%r14\n\t"
      "pushq %%r15\n\t"
      "pushfq\n\t"
      "movq %%rsp, %2\n\t" // save rsp into context sp (end of context mem)
      "movq %4, %%rsp\n\t" // restore stackptr into rsp
      :"+m"(curr_thd->stackptr)   
      ,"+m"(curr_thd->stackbp)    
      ,"+m"(curr_thd->context_sp)
      :"m"(curr_thd->context_mem) 
      ,"m"(curr_thd->stackptr)    
      :"rsp"
    );
  }

  curr_thd->state = WAITING;
  curr_thd = thd;

  // Calls function if thread is not running
  if(thd->state == READY)
  {
    thd->state = ACTIVE;
    thd->funcptr(thd->param);
  }
  else
  {
    // Restore context
    {
      asm volatile
      (
        "movq %0, %%rbp\n\t" // restore stackbp into rbp
        "movq %1, %%rsp\n\t" // point to context memory to pop
        "popfq\n\t"
        "popq %%r15\n\t"
        "popq %%r14\n\t"
        "popq %%r13\n\t"
        "popq %%r12\n\t"
        "popq %%r11\n\t"
        "popq %%r10\n\t"
        "popq %%r9\n\t"
        "popq %%r8\n\t"
        "popq %%rdi\n\t"
        "popq %%rsi\n\t"
        "popq %%rdx\n\t"
        "popq %%rcx\n\t"
        "popq %%rbx\n\t"
        "popq %%rax\n\t"
        "movq %2, %%rsp\n\t" // point to TCB stack pointer
        :
        :"m"(thd->stackbp)
        ,"m"(thd->context_sp)
        ,"m"(thd->stackptr)
        :"rsp"
      );
    }
  }
}
} // end namespace
void* print1(void *a)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i< 20; i++)
  {
    std::cout<<"Print1 i: "<<i<<std::endl;
    if((i+1)%4==0)
        CORO::thd_yield();
  }
  return NULL;
}

void* print2(void *a)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; i< 20; i++)
  {
    std::cout<<"Print2 i: "<<i<<std::endl;
    if((i+1)%4==0)
        CORO::thd_yield();
  }
  return NULL;
}


int main()
{
  CORO::ThreadID id;
  CORO::thd_init();
  id = CORO::new_thd(print2, NULL);
  print1(NULL);
}
```

Comment: What do you suppose is in RSP when you do `"movq %3, %%rsp\n\t"`?  And what do you suppose it going to happen when you do `"movq %1, %%rsp\n\t"`?

Comment: I believe RSP would be pointing to the start of context memory for movq %3. For movq %1, RSP would be pointing to the end of context memory, which is start of context memory + number of times I pushed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your first asm statement overwirtes `rsp` with an undefined value as you read an input after writing to a non early clobber output; for operations like this it should read the output parameter, `curr_thd->stackptr` should not be an input parameter.

When starting a new thread, your code does not switch to a new stack, but uses the old thread stack. This explains your crash.

Your second asm statement restores register values suitable for leaving the first asm statement, but exits with a stack state and instruction pointer suitable for leaving second asm statement; this results in undefined behaviour. If the function is copied in some way, it will also be in the wrong copy of the context switch function.

GCC inline assembler must not alter the contents of registers that are not in the output or clobber list, nor may control enter one asm statement and leave another (in the same thread); doing so results in undefined behaviour. Therefore saving the context and restoring it cannot be separate asm statements.

You should use a single block of assembly for the context switch. Especially for context switches, it is simplest to avoid inline assembly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But do you mind elaborating a little more? In the first asm statement, do you mean that I should early clobber stackptr as it is written to in the first line and then read from later on? For the second asm statement, what do you mean by register values and stack being suitable for leaving the first/second statements? Thanks!